# Fast way to run several piped commands on many big text files

Tags: batch-file, visual-c++, parallel-processing

I have a huge collection of data stored in text files (one day's of data in each file, max size around 1.5gb). They are data feeds so they have to be processed to human readable format, which is done by a several C-programs (not written by me).

I get one day's of some specific data by f.ex running the command

```
decode.exe < ResourceTXT/itch-20140530.txt | select.exe -I 101 | bookgen.exe  -t -r | dump.exe > Output/20140530.txt
```

I have created another simple C++ command line utility that gives me several of these "queries", for a given date range and options

For example,

```
query 20140530 20140601 101 B -t -r
```

gives me the output

```
decode.exe < ResourceTXT/itch-20140530.txt | select.exe -I 101 | bookgen.exe  -t -r | dump.exe > Output/20140530.txt
decode.exe < ResourceTXT/itch-20140531.txt | select.exe -I 101 | bookgen.exe  -t -r | dump.exe > Output/20140531.txt
decode.exe < ResourceTXT/itch-20140601.txt | select.exe -I 101 | bookgen.exe  -t -r | dump.exe > Output/20140601.txt
```

which I can pipe to for example *run.bat*. I can then run this *bat* file, have each text file processed sequentially, and then merge everything into one single file with

```
copy /b *.txt my_data.txt
```

Then delete the intermediate .txt files and I'm done.

But this is a very slow way to do it if I need to generate data for 100 days.

I know I can start 100 instances of a windows command with the *start* command. But for this to work here, I need to create 100 .bat files, each containing the "query" to be run, then create another final.bat file that starts all of these bat file like:

```
start batfile1.bat
start batfile2.bat
...
start batfile100.bat
```

and then run *final.bat*.

This feels like a cumbersome and a bit inelegant way to do it. Since I'm a newbie, I would just like to confirm whether this is an OKAY way to deal with my problem, or whether I am doing something very stupid, or have overlooked anything important. Thank you.

note: I'm helping a guy with this, he wants to keep everything in a Visual C++ project (the original C-program to handle the raw data feeds [decode.exe, etc.] have been ported to this project). So that means everything should be done with C++ or a Windows batch file.

EDIT: 
Here is the info Aacini requested:

First method:

```
Start: 16:01:12,62
End:   16:02:02,12
```

Second method:

```
Start decode:  16:03:32,05
Start select:  16:04:28,49
Start bookgen: 16:04:37,11
Start dump:    16:04:37,35
End:           16:04:38,04
```

Wow, so it seems that it would be best to just run decode.exe on every single text file, and store that binary data for use later instead...? (But then another concern is that these binary encoded files are actually *twice* the size of the original data in the .txt files...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points you may test in order to improve the efficiency of your method.

In first place, the efficiency of several processes linked by pipes depends on several factors, but anyways the final result is always tied to the slowest process. This means that we may improve the general efficiency if we identify the slowest process and give more CPU time to it.

You may start performing some timing tests; for example, first test your original method this way:

```
echo Start: %time%
decode.exe < ResourceTXT/itch-20140530.txt | select.exe -I 101 | bookgen.exe  -t -r | dump.exe > Output/20140530.txt
echo End:   %time%
```

Then, separate the piped processes into individual processes that uses temporary files:

```
echo Start decode:  %time%
decode.exe < ResourceTXT/itch-20140530.txt > temp1.txt
echo Start select:  %time%
select.exe -I 101 < temp1.txt > temp2.txt
echo Start bookgen: %time%
bookgen.exe  -t -r < temp2.txt > temp3.txt
echo Start dump:    %time%
dump.exe < temp3.txt > Output/20140530.txt
echo End:           %time%
```

If the *total time* of this method is much larger than the previous one, then it means that the computer have several CPU cores and the parallel processes are properly synchronized by the OS. However, the total time of this method could be similar or even slightly smaller than the previous one not only because the CPU have a few CPU cores, but because each process run at its maximum speed with no need for start/stop synchonizations required to wait for the data generated by previous process. Of course, the second method requires a much larger disk space for the temporary files, so in this case we need to use more memory to get less time (as usual).

In the second method we can also identify the time taken by each individual process and then use they to distribute the available CPU cores into all processes. For example, we can use each CPU core to run more than one of the fastest processes and just one of the slowest ones; the idea is to waste the less possible CPU processing time. You may identify the number of cores with `echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%`.

Writting a Batch file that repeats 100 of your processes with 100 different dates is relatively simple, but I will wait for the result of previous timing tests so I can write the best solution for you. Please, post the results editing the original question and just leave me a comment here as an advice of that.

**EDIT**: First version of solution

Here it is the first version of the solution. I used the method of start several parallel instances of the four piped .exe programs as you originally suggested because the other method is too complex. Most parts of this program should look similar to your query C++ program. The interesting section is the control of the number of active instances, but the method used is straightforward. There are several ways to count the number of active instances of a program (like `for /F ... in ('tasklist ... ^| findstr ...') do ...`), but I prefer to use just internal Batch commands because the repeated execution of tasklist.exe and findstr.exe external commands (besides one additional copy of cmd.exe used in the `for /F` command, plus one additional copy for each side of the pipe) consume too much CPU time. The method I used, based on the presence of *flag files*, is very simple and efficient: a flag file is created before each instance is started, and it is deleted when the instance ends. This way, to know how many instances are active just count the number of flag files.

Theoretically, this method should reach the best efficiency when the number of active instances is equal to the number of CPU cores (8 in your case); however, there are several factors that may affect the real behaviour. Although is possible that the program itself modify the number of active instances and calculate how the efficiency changes, the code required for such management is large and complex, so I opted for a much simpler solution. The program allows to manually set the number of parallel instances and the number of seconds that the method waits in the cycle that checks when an instance ends. If this second number is too small, the cycle will take too much CPU time; if the number is too large, the method will wait too much time after an instance ends before starting the next one (wasting available CPU time).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~4" neq "" goto begin

echo Usage: %0 numOfProcesses secondsToWait startDate endDate [options]
echo/
echo    numOfProcesses - Number of simultaneous queries to run in parallel
echo    secondsToWait  - Seconds to wait between process checking
echo    start/end Date - In YYYYMMDD format
echo    options        - First options are for select.exe, followed by
echo                     B opts for bookgen.exe, and D opts for dump.exe
echo/
echo For example:
echo    %0 8 10 20140530 20140601 -I 101 B -t -r
goto :EOF

:begin

set    "maxProcs=%1"  & shift
set /A "seconds=%1+1" & shift
set    "startDate=%1" & shift
set    "endDate=%1"

rem Get the options for each process
set "proc=S"
set "procs= B D "
:nextOpt
   shift
   if "%1" equ "" goto continue
   if "!procs: %1 =!" neq "%procs%" (
      set "proc=%1"
   ) else (
      set "%proc%_opts=!%proc%_opts! %1"
   )
goto nextOpt
:continue

rem Initialize date variables
set M=100
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A M+=1
   set "daysPerMonth[!M!]=1%%a"
)
set /A Y=%startDate:~0,4%, M=1%startDate:~4,2%, D=1%startDate:~6,2%, leap=Y%%4
if %leap% equ 0 set "daysPerMonth[102]=129"

rem Start the initial set of N parallel processes
del query.log *.flg 2> NUL
set startTime=%time%
set /A query=0, active=0
:nextQuery
   set /A query+=1
   echo %query%- %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1% Started @ %time% >> query.log
   echo X > %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1%.flg
   start /B cmd.exe /D /C decode.exe ^< ResourceTXT/itch-%Y%%M:~1%%D:~1%.txt ^| select.exe %S_opts% ^| bookgen.exe %B_opts% ^| dump.exe %D_opts% ^> Output/%Y%%M:~1%%D:~1%.txt ^& del %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1%.flg
   ECHO Query %query%- %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1% started
   set /A D+=1
   if %D% gtr !daysPerMonth[%M%]! (
      set /A  D=101, M+=1
      if !M! gtr 112 (
         set /A M=101, Y+=1, leap=Y%%4
         if !leap! equ 0 set "daysPerMonth[102]=129"
      )
   )
   if %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1% gtr %endDate% goto waitEndQueries
   set /A active+=1
if %active% lss %maxProcs% goto nextQuery

ECHO/
ECHO Initial set of %maxProcs% queries started, there are pending queries

rem Cycle of: wait seconds, count active processes, start a new one
:waitQuery
   ECHO/
   ECHO Waiting for an active query to end, in order to start the next one
   ping -n %seconds% localhost > NUL
   set active=0
   for %%a in (*.flg) do set /A active+=1
   if %active% geq %maxProcs% goto waitQuery
   set /A query+=1
   echo %query%- %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1% Started @ %time% >> query.log
   echo X > %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1%.flg
   start /B cmd.exe /D /C decode.exe ^< ResourceTXT/itch-%Y%%M:~1%%D:~1%.txt ^| select.exe %S_opts% ^| bookgen.exe %B_opts% ^| dump.exe %D_opts% ^> Output/%Y%%M:~1%%D:~1%.txt ^& del %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1%.flg
   ECHO Query %query%- %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1% started
   set /A D+=1
   if %D% gtr !daysPerMonth[%M%]! (
      set /A D=101, M+=1
      if !M! gtr 112 (
         set /A M=101, Y+=1, leap=Y%%4
         if !leap! equ 0 set "daysPerMonth[102]=129"
      )
   )
if %Y%%M:~1%%D:~1% leq %endDate% goto waitQuery

echo/
echo All requested queries has been started

rem Wait for the rest of active processes to end
:waitEndQueries
ping -n %seconds% localhost > NUL
if exist *.flg goto waitEndQueries

rem Complete the whole process:
(
echo/
echo Queries from %startDate% to %endDate%
echo Total queries processed: %query%
echo Start time: %startTime%
echo End time:   %time%
) >> query.log

copy /b *.txt my_data.ok
del *.txt
ren my_data.ok my_data.txt
```

I suggest you to do a few tests processing files for about 15-20 days. Start with 8 active instances and 1 second to wait, then repeat the test with 1 instance more and 1 instance less. If one of these changes result in less total time, repeat the test with 1 instance more/less in the same direction. When you find the best number of instances, do a similar test incrementing the seconds to wait. After that, you may process your 100 or any number of files in the fastest possible way.

I'll appreciate it if you may post some results of the testings. If you have any problem or question, leave me a comment.

Comment: I have edited my post. Thank you! And the echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% gives 8

Comment: Ok. With 8 cores we may have 1 core to run `select|bookgen|dump` and the rest of cores to run an instance of `decode` each; this means that in a given moment may be up to 7 different `temp1.txt` files, although each one of them will be deleted as soon as they are processed by `select|...`. So the important question is this: is there enough free disk space for all of them?

Comment: Yes, the disk space should not be a limitation. Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot and sorry for the very late reply. I have tried your approach and it seems to work very well, but I will have to spend some time to understand the entire script. Thanks again